# SFTP Chilkat error "Expected KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP"

Tags: sftp, chilkat

### I am trying to connect to an SFTP but am getting the following error from Chilkat in the function sftp.Connect(hostname, port)...

DllDate: Dec 22 2010
    UnlockPrefix: *******
    Username: 
    Component: .NET 2.0
    SftpVersion: 0
    hostname: **.**.***.***
    port: 22
    ConnectTimeoutMs: 50000

calling ConnectSocket2
    This is an IPV4 numeric address...
    Connect using IPV4.
    ipAddress: **.**.**.***
    socketHandle: 0x804
    ai_addrlen: 16
    ai_addr: 0200 0016 4B7F 64D8 0000 0000 0000 0000

```
myIP_3: **.***.***.***
myPort_3: *****
connect successful.
Established TCP/IP connection with SSH server
clientIdentifier: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Local:_May_11_2009_17:22:38
initialDataFromSshServer: SSH-2.0-0.0 

serverVersion: SSH-2.0-0.0 
KeyExchangeAlgs:
  algorithm: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
  algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
  algorithm: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
HostKeyAlgs:
  algorithm: ssh-dss
EncCS:
  algorithm: aes256-cbc
  algorithm: aes192-cbc
  algorithm: aes128-cbc
  algorithm: twofish-cbc
  algorithm: blowfish-cbc
  algorithm: 3des-cbc
  algorithm: arcfour
EncSC:
  algorithm: aes256-cbc
  algorithm: aes192-cbc
  algorithm: aes128-cbc
  algorithm: twofish-cbc
  algorithm: blowfish-cbc
  algorithm: 3des-cbc
  algorithm: arcfour
MacCS:
  algorithm: hmac-sha1
  algorithm: hmac-sha1-96
  algorithm: hmac-md5
  algorithm: hmac-md5-96
MacSC:
  algorithm: hmac-sha1
  algorithm: hmac-sha1-96
  algorithm: hmac-md5
  algorithm: hmac-md5-96
CompCS:
  algorithm: zlib
  algorithm: none
CompSC:
  algorithm: zlib
  algorithm: none
Encryption: 256-bit AES
Encryption: 256-bit AES
MAC: HMAC-SHA1
MAC: HMAC-SHA1
Compression: none
Compression: none
Key Exchange: DH Group Exchange SHA1
Host Key Algorithm: DSS
numBits: 160
pbits: 2048
```

Using GEX Group.
    Sending KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST...
    pbits: 2048

Unexpected message received.  Expected KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP.
    msgType: 1

### Failed.

I am primarily using the 4 functions to connect to SFTP

```
sftp.UnlockComponent(ChilkatKey);
sftp.Connect(hostname, port);
sftp.AuthenticatePw(username, password);
sftp.InitializeSftp();
```

What am I missing ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

correct order should be like as yours:

```
sftp.UnlockComponent(ChilkatKey);
sftp.Connect(hostname, port);
sftp.AuthenticatePw(username, password);
sftp.InitializeSftp();
```

but after those guys, u need to call OpenDir and ReadDir(if you need to get files count on remote folder) methods like;

```
string handler = sftp.OpenDir("remote_path");
SFtpDir compassDir = sftp.ReadDir(handler);
```

to just download a file you don't need to call ReadDir but OpenDir must be called.
After the populating compassDir object you can get file count by;

```
int fileAmount = compassDir.NumFilesAndDirs
```

or you can download files by name like;

```
sftp.DownloadFileByName("local_path","Remote_path_with_file_name");
```

Sorry for the typo error.